# minifying signalr hubs auto-generated proxy

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

My app is using a SignalR 1.1.2 on ASP.NET MVC
It has the following call in the View

This uses the auto-generated hub.
At this point all client and server side methods are done.

Can I get a copy of the 'hubs.js' file I get when I paste this
link into the browser.

I want to add a new javascript file to the BundleConfig.cs so I 
can minify this file and try and improve the performance of my app.

Hope someone can advise, I have done it and it seems to work, I just
want to be sure that I will not loose the ability to shift gears to
websockets, SSE, Forever-Frame depending on what the client and server
can negotiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you navigate to the /signalr/hubs uri you can save this javascript file and put it in a bundle.  Of course if you change anything to do with signalr then it might not work.  But this is for release.  Just a note that this 1.1.2

Answer (score 2):

MVC web optimization  does not support dynamic scripts. I did it like this in my last project, it doesnt help with minifying but you can add the static script to the bundle config

```
(function ($) {
    var dynamicScripts = ["signalr/hubs", "eventAggregation/events"];
    $.each(dynamicScripts, function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: this,
            cache: true,
            dataType: "script",
            async: false
        });
    });
} (jQuery));
```

Comment: Very interesting bit of code.  I didn't know ajax could have a dataType of 'script'.  I have used the cache attribute but never used with this dataType.  What about the async attribute, what if it were true, might this help stop any ui threads from blocking?

Comment: It will use the same type of caching as for static JS files

Comment: so you put this bit of code into a static script file and then add this file to the bundler?